# Como extrair informações especificas de um texto em Python?

Tags: python

Eu tenho um texto contendo dados de uma empresa, mas estes dados estão desorganizados. Como eu poderia extrair algum dado específico nesse texto usando Python?

Texto:

```
{"atividade_principal":[{"text":"Consultoria em tecnologia da informação","code":"62.04-0-
00"}],"data_situacao":"22/02/2019","tipo":"MATRIZ","nome":"JEFFERSON SIQUEIRA BALIVO TECNOLOGIA EM PAGAMENTOS DIGITAIS LTDA","uf":"SP","telefone":"(14) 9999-
9999","email":"lucasmontanini@gmail.com","atividades_secundarias":[{"text":"Atividades de cobranças 
e informações cadastrais","code":"82.91-1-00"},{"text":"Atividades de 
teleatendimento","code":"82.20-2-00"},{"text":"Preparação de documentos e serviços especializados de 
apoio administrativo não especificados anteriormente","code":"82.19-9-99"},{"text":"Serviços 
combinados de escritório e apoio administrativo","code":"82.11-3-00"},{"text":"Atividades de 
intermediação e agenciamento de serviços e negócios em geral, exceto imobiliários","code":"74.90-1-
04"},{"text":"Marketing direto","code":"73.19-0-03"},{"text":"Promoção de vendas","code":"73.19-0-
02"},{"text":"Correspondentes de instituições financeiras","code":"66.19-3-02"},
{"text":"Administração de cartões de crédito","code":"66.13-4-00"},{"text":"Desenvolvimento de 
programas de computador sob encomenda","code":"62.01-5-01"},{"text":"Aluguel de outras máquinas e 
equipamentos comerciais e industriais não especificados anteriormente, sem operador","code":"77.39-
0-99"},{"text":"Comércio varejista especializado de equipamentos e suprimentos de 
informática","code":"47.51-2-01"}],"qsa":[{"qual":"49-Sócio-Administrador","nome":"JEFFERSON 
SIQUEIRA BALIVO"}],"situacao":"ATIVA","bairro":"SANTO ANTONIO","logradouro":"R TREZE DE 
MAIO","numero":"675","cep":"17.202-180","municipio":"JAU","porte":"MICRO 
EMPRESA","abertura":"22/02/2019","natureza_juridica":"206-2 - Sociedade Empresária 
Limitada","fantasia":"EZ BANK","cnpj":"32.862.332/0001-71","ultima_atualizacao":"2022-04-
12T13:04:31.568Z","status":"OK","complemento":"","efr":"","motivo_situacao":"","situacao_especial":"
","data_situacao_especial":"","capital_social":"10000.00","extra":{},"billing":
{"free":true,"database":true}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você tem uma string no formato `JSON` (JavaScript Object Notation). Este objeto pode ser facilmente lido pela biblioteca `json` do Python, que converte uma string `JSON` no seu objeto equivalente.

Por exemplo

```py
import json

json_str = '{"some_property":{"some_value":10},"some_other_property":20}'

data = json.loads(json_str)

print(data['some_property']['some_value'])
```

irá imprimir na tela o valor numérico `10`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu sabia que essas chaves e aspas nesse texto serviam pra alguma coisa kkk